# Use @Value to inject value from properties file into @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a value stored in an `application.properties` file in the resources directory. I want to inject this value in a class with the `@Configuration` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Xconfig {

    @Value("${x}")
    private final String x;

}
```

application.properties:

```
x=hello
```

This works for @Component/@Service classes but not for the @Configuration. Error message:

> Parameter 1 of constructor in xConfig required a bean
>   of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.

Comment: either remove `final` from `String x`, or declare your constructor manually (and remove `@RequiredArgsConstructor`) and attach @Value to the parameter.

Comment: How is this cdi related?

Answer (score 3):

Replacing the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation with an own constructor solves the issue.

```
public Xconfig(@Value("${x}") final String x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```