# Could not resolve YML @Value injected in a @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963186/use-value-to-inject-value-from-properties-file-into-configuration-class) seems to suggest, this should work fine

```yaml
# application-dev.yml
gateway:
  publicEndpoints:
    - /api/v1/example,
    - /api/v1/another-example
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity // does this annotation matter?
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final String[] publicEndpoints;

    public SecurityConfig(@Value("${gateway.publicEndpoints}") String[] publicEndpoints) {
        this.publicEndpoints = publicEndpoints; // a breakpoint here never gets hit
    }

    // ...

}
```

However, I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'gateway.publicEndpoints' in value "${gateway.publicEndpoints}"
```

I tried removing comma(s) in the yml file but get the same result

I also tried

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Value("${gateway.publicEndpoints}")
    private String[] publicEndpoints;
```

Got the same exception

The profile is correct (`dev`):

```
The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
```

Salvatore Bernardo's proposal to use `@ConfigurationProperties` *does* help, however I'm still curious why I can't successfully use `@Value` in that code

Salvatore also hypothesized that it may be due to the `yml` format that `@Value` seems to not support (the doc [does not corroborate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) that idea)

Another guy on SO [had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556677/spring-boot-load-value-from-yaml-file), and it appears it was due to wrong identation (my identation is fine)

What is the cause of that behavior?

Spring Boot 3.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for complex structure (List, Map) use `ConfigurationProperties`. I replicated here https://github.com/sbernardo/spring-issues-examples/tree/main/sof-questions-77691200 your problem and fixed using `ConfigurationProperties`

This problem seems similar to [Can't get Java see my custom YAML property in a Spring Boot app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646394/cant-get-java-see-my-custom-yaml-property-in-a-spring-boot-app) .

`@Value` is good to use with simple value, for example `String` value.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you. But what if I want to use `@Value`? Why can't I do it?

Comment: Seems is `yml` format the problem, I tried with `application.properties` file and works with `@Value` annotation. It's a bit strange I know.. but I can't answer honestly :D You can find at same link the example with yaml and properties file

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), though, says ymls *are* supported. Maybe, I need to do some additional setup?

Comment: Sorry for missed answer, I was away from pc. I just found this really old issue in Spring project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16381 and seems that with a representation of yaml. If you use `publicEndpoints: /api/v1/example, /api/v1/another-example` works as expected. Honestly I think this is a workaround :D

Comment: I updated the project here https://github.com/sbernardo/spring-issues-examples/tree/main/sof-questions-77691200 using only `@Value` without `ConfigurationProperties` with yaml file

Comment: _"There are a number of comments after the issue was closed that we've all seen. If the issue hasn't been reopened, that's because we're not considering implementing this at this time. This may be revisited in the future, in which case the issue will be reopened."_ I start to suspect we may one day regret bitterly about coupling our code so much with that Spring thing. Bob Martin was right

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be some kind of problem with the *.yml format. If you spell the parameters with commas, like this:

```
gateway:
    publicEndpoints: /api/v1/example, /api/v1/another-example
```

everything reads fine

Although the documentation says that the list is generated in *.yml using  "a dash and a space" [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html)